# Cannot import JavaScript in HTML because of MIME type error

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

I'm getting this error when i attempt to import my JavaScript file:

[image: error]

Not sure if this link works but I've tried linking to Replit:
https://replit.com/@Freyseee/PostNord-simulator?s=app#app.js

**Relevant file locations:**

- simple.js
- public/html/videofeed.html
- public/js/stream.js

[image: files]
[image: files]

**videofeed.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

  <!-- javascript -->
  <script src='../libraries/tracking.js'></script>
  <script src=".../simple.js" defer></script>
  <script src="../js/websocket.js" defer></script>
  <script src="../js/stream.js" defer></script>
  <title>Simple websocket</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Stream</h1>

  <img id="stream"
    src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/plain-cyan-solid-color-background-260nw-1922086277.jpg">
  <canvas id="canvas">

  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

**simple.js**

```
let count = 0;
let mc = [];
let homepage = [];


function websocket(wss) {
  wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    console.log("Client connected");

    ws.on("message", function(message, isBinary) {
      message = isBinary ? message : message.toString();
      console.log(message);
      if (message == "mc") {
        mc.push(ws);
      }
      if (message == "hp") {
        homepage.push(ws);
      }
      mc.forEach(async (client) => {
        await client.send("m");
      }),
        homepage.forEach(async (client) => {
          await client.send(message);
        }
        );
    })

    ws.on("close", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
  });

  setInterval(() => {
  }, 1000);
}

//Inform clients (called in stream.js)
function itsYellow() {
  mc.forEach(async (client) => {
    await client.send("gul");
  })
}
function itsCyan() {
  mc.forEach(async (client) => {
    await client.send("blaa");
  })
}
function itsMagenta() {
  mc.forEach(async (client) => {
    await client.send("lilla");
  })
}

module.exports = websocket;
```

**stream.js**

```
// source: https://bensonruan.com/color-tracking-with-tracking-js/

var image = document.getElementById("stream");
const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

setTimeout(() => {
  ctx.canvas.width = image.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = image.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}, 1000);

//source: https://tangiblejs.com/posts/tracking-color-blobs-in-webcam-feed-using-tracking-js
var img = document.getElementById('stream');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var tracker = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);

tracker.on('track', function(e) {

  //Find colour
  if (e.data.length !== 0) {
    e.data.forEach(function(rect) {
      console.log(rect);

      //Inform clients
      if (rect.color === "yellow") {
        itsYellow();
      }
      else if (rect.color === "magenta") {
        itsMagenta();
      }
      else if (rect.color === "cyan") {
        itsCyan();
      }
    });

  }

});

tracking.track(img, tracker, { camera: true });
```

I've tried changing how I refer to the script but I can't seem to get it to work. I've included files in case they are needed and a description of how my files are "arranged". I need to use Simple.js because I need to send a message to a client.

Comment: The server says it is an HTML document. So either (a) it is an error page or (b) the server is misconfigured. Start by looking at the response in the Network tab of your browser to see what the HTML document says.

Comment: What do you expect `...` to do in a URL?

Comment: Also consider what "public" means and why the JS file you can't access is the only one that isn't in that folder.

Comment: the ' ... ' is to try and exit the "public" folder so I can reach the simple.js file

Comment: try changing `<script src='your-scripts.js'></script>` lines to `<script type="application/javascript" src="your-scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: @V.Salles — The type attribute tells the browser what type of content it should expect the URL to return so it can avoid making the request if it doesn't support that data type. It won't magically stop the server from returning an HTML document describing the error.

Comment: I also get the error: GET https://postnord-simulator.freyseee.repl.co/html/..../simple.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: @Freyseee — Exactly. You need to provide the URL to the script. That means (a) the script has to be given a URL. You can't request arbitrary things from the server's hard disk. That would be a huge security problem! You can only request things which are public. and (b) you have to use real URL syntax (triple dot doesn't mean anything).

Comment: The attribute did not work. I'm thinking you are right about the folder I'm just not sure why

Comment: It is not about the mime type, most surely you are loading an html 404 error page instead of your script, because you cannot access a non public folder from your javascript

Comment: It makes much more sense now. However, I'm not sure how I'm gonna send messages to my clients if I can't import the script in my HTML

Comment: @Quentin yes, perfect. I also forgot to mention that he used three dots on the line that adds the simple.js script

Answer (score -1):

you are using three dots

```
<script src=".../simple.js" defer></script>
```

i think it should be:

```
<script src="../simple.js" defer></script>
```

--- EDIT ---
is the `simple.js` outside the public ?

```
<script src="../../simple.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: can you write a comment if u gave me ( - 1 ) xd